# How to handle click events in UISplitView nested controllers

Tags: ios, mono, xamarin.ios

I'm Monotouch for iOS development.
I've got a SplitView for iPad and the main view controller is UITabBar with UINavigation inside and UITableView nested in it. Thats a quite complicated controllers chain. And I need to handle row click event in TableView and return it back up to UISplitView to make an appropriate action on DetailView controller.
Is it a good design to define an event in each controller in the controllers chain and transit the event from the very end to the very begining calling the intermediate events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to keep things simple. Usually the splitViewController is a property of the `AppDelegate` (if not, you can just add one). So you can access the splitViewController from anywhere in your app by calling

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] splitViewController] anyMethodYouWantToCallOnTheSplitVC];
```

Comment: Can you please provide a relevant C# example or comment out the code?

Comment: Why C#? We're talking about iOS here?!?!

Comment: I haven't used Monotouch, so I'm not sure about how that works. But I guess it should either be `UIApplication.sharedInstance.delegate.splitViewController.anyMethodYouWantToCallOnTheSplitVC()` or `UIApplication.sharedInstance().delegate().splitViewController().anyMethodYouWantToCallOnTheSplitVC()`

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I was looking for! Global access to AppDelegate.

Answer (score 1):

@Tobi was on the right track, you can get access your AppDelegate using `var myApp = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate as AppDelegate;` and at that point either reference the public instance of your UISplitViewController or call a public method from `myApp`.